# rselenium driver error using apply loop

Tags: r, selenium, runtime-error, rselenium

I am using rselenium to automate page navigation in Firefox. My rscript imports a data frame for different conditions and creates a custom function which is then called using the apply command. In the function, each column is referenced through something like this:

```
#create the function
example <- function(dat) {
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(dat[[column1]]))
    #Enters text from the column in the web driver
}
apply(df, 1, example) #Should repeat the function for each row of the data
```

I have multiple columns that I'm referencing in the apply function so that the data from each one can have a different interaction for the web driver - for example, `dat[[column2]]`, `dat[[column3]]`, and so on. Mostly I'm just sending keys (tabs and arrow keys after `findElement(using = 'tag name', 'body')` or clicking a button that I find with the `findElement` function and its id.

I have the script executing and it works fine the first time through, but when it starts over I am getting errors. I would like selenium to open the starting url again, and repeat the navigation using the next line of the data frame. But, what happens is r locks up or reports an error:

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchDriver
     Detail: A session is either terminated or not started
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I think that it traces back to the `findElements` calls in the beginning of the function or the `sendKeysToElement` call. I have tried closing, quitting, and re-initializing the remote driver but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Are there any tips for troubleshooting? Or a good way to do repeated navigation with selenium in r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by recasting my code from an `apply` function to a `for(...)` loop. The function I had created was changed minimally.

- I started the web driver in the beginning of the loop

  ```
  remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE))       
  remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
  remDr$navigate(url)
  ```
- Throughout the loop I was careful to pass variables to methods relying on `rselenium` like `findElement` and `sendKeysToElement`. That looked something like this:

  ```
  nextBtn(pageBody, remDr)
  ```

  which was shorthand for:

  ```
  nextBtn <- function(element=pageBody, driver=remDr) {
    Sys.sleep(.5)
    driver$findElement(using = 'id',value = "NextButton")$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(2.5)
  }
  ```

  I think that because the methods were called in separate functions, they required being pointed to the right driver elements (even though I had tried to set the default)
- And at the end of the `for` loop, code closed the web driver down:

  ```
  remDr$close()
  remDr$quit()
  ```

The actual call of the loop was

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  surveys(df[i,])
}
```

The end result is that the loop functions. It opens a new driver instance each time but there weren't errors. References to a specific column were still made with `df[[mold0to2]]`.